# View Log from Map/Reduce Task

Tags: hadoop

I know that i can find the map/reduce task log inside: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs/.

Are there a friendly way to see it?

For example, when i clicked `http://127.0.0.1:8088/cluster/`, I can see all jobs executed in the cluster. Then i clicked in a FINISHED job. But now, when i try to click in `Tracking URL:  History` it gives me an error, Why can i see the task logs from here?

I would like to see the stderr, stdout and syslog from each task.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Job Browser from HUE

or Use the command

yarn logs -applicationId  [OPTIONS]

general options are:
 -appOwner    AppOwner (assumed to be current user if
                                 not specified)
 -containerId      ContainerId (must be specified if node
                                 address is specified)
 -nodeAddress      NodeAddress in the format nodename:port
                                 (must be specified if container id is
                                 specified)

Example:  yarn logs -applicationId application_1414530900704_0007